# how to remove a column of a list on SharePoint

Tags: windows-server-2008, sharepoint-2007

I am using SharePoint 2007 + Windows Server 2008 with SharePoint 2007's publishing portal template. I have created a list with datasheet view on a page (I add the list by adding a Web Part -> then select the list control to add it as a web part to the page.) When create the list, I have added 5 columns, and inserted some rows.

My question is, how to remove one column of the list?

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 0):

The first column cant be removed as far as I can tell, but you can rename it.

The other columns are easy to delete: just go to the 'list settings 'page, click on the column name, as though you were going to edit it, then click on 'delete'.